# Using LinqToEntities to obtain all records having property equal to maximum value, as IQueryable

Tags: linq-to-entities, iqueryable

I have the following linq to entities query:

```
(from p in _db.TrialParticipants
 where p.StudyCentreId == newParticipant.StudyCentreId &&
         p.HasCyanoticHeartDisease == newParticipant.HasCyanoticHeartDisease &&
         p.HasChronicLungDisease == newParticipant.HasChronicLungDisease &&
         p.RespiratorySupportAtRandomisation.RandomisationCategory == newParticipant.RespiratorySupportAtRandomisation.RandomisationCategory
 group p by p.BlockNumber into g
 orderby g.Key descending
 select g).FirstOrDefault();
```

What I would like to do is get all participants with the highest value of the blocknumber property (this will be between 1 and 8 participants) as an IQueryable - that is, i would like to be able to run different queries under different circumstances, such as Count(), Select(p=>p.PropertyA).ToList() etc without having executed the query prior.

The problem is, the only way I can see to get this group (having the highest value of blocknumber) is to execute .FirstOrDefault() on the IGrouping, which (as I understand it) will execute the query against the database.

I could run a separate query first to get the maximum value, but I do not wish to have the where clause logic repeated (retyped) at multiple points (as this would feel like bad coding practice).

Is there a way to get the above output as an IQueryable<Participants> (note NOT as an IQueryable<IGrouping<int,Participants>>) without repeating the where clause logic. Thank you.

Comment: Actually the edited code snippet is perfectly readable and probably sufficiently efficient. Why would you need something more tricky/cryptic?

Comment: Absolutely fair point - I posted the question before I had come up with the second solution, which is completely adequate, but I love to see synactically clever answers provided by professionals like yourself. As such, I will edit my post to put the second piece of code as a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the query to

```
IQueryable<TrialParticipant> partsInGroup = _db.TrialParticipants.Where(p=>p.StudyCentreId == newParticipant.StudyCentreId &&
    p.HasCyanoticHeartDisease == newParticipant.HasCyanoticHeartDisease &&
    p.HasChronicLungDisease == newParticipant.HasChronicLungDisease &&
    p.RespiratorySupportAtRandomisation.RandomisationCategory == newParticipant.RespiratorySupportAtRandomisation.RandomisationCategory);

int? maxBlockNumberInGrp = partsInGroup.Max(p=>(int?)p.BlockNumber);
if (maxBlockNumberInGrp.HasValue)
{
    return partsInGroup.Where(p=>p.BlockNumber==maxBlockNumberInGrp.Value);
}      
return (new TrialParticipant[0]).AsQueryable();
```

however, for cleverness sake, I would love to see a single query that achieves this (even if that query ran 2 queries against the database)